# Convert file of bytes to ints Python

Tags: python, int, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reading integers from binary file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163459/reading-integers-from-binary-file-in-python)

I've read the solution to a similar problem here: [convert a string of bytes into an int (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-python) but I'm not quite sure how to repurpose it for my needs.

I have a .bin file which is just a sequence of bytes. Every set of 4 bytes represents a 32-bit number. I am trying to use the struct module as described in that linked question to convert every set of 4 bytes to an integer and print them to a new file. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Clearly it's not that ambiguous since Steve understood and answered it with exactly what I was looking for within minutes after I posted the question. In any case, go ahead and close if you would like since I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read [Read ints from file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163459/reading-integers-from-binary-file-in-python)
It is even more straightforward from that question.

I have not checked the following code but something along the spirit of

```
fin = open("hi.bmp", "rb")
out = open("values.txt","rw")
value = struct.unpack('i', fin.read(4))[0]
out.write("%d\n" % value) # just loop over the 2 last lines
out.close()
fin.close()
```

should do the trick, if you want to record the ints as readable integers in another file.