# Faster way to convert a large bytes object into a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a large bytes object (raw data from a 16-bit WAVE file with about 8 million samples) that I need to convert to a list of integers to do some processing on. So far I used list comprehension and `int.from_bytes` for the conversion, but I have noticed it is taking a considerable amount of time. I am wondering whether there is a faster solution.

Here is my current method:

```
data = [int.from_bytes(raw[i * sampwidth:((i + 1) * sampwidth)], "little", signed=True) for i in range(len(raw) // sampwidth)]
```

On my machine this method is taking about 9 seconds per file (I have multiple files) on a single core, and I would like to know whether I am pushing Python's limits, or whether there exists a more optimal method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713266/5267751 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use scipy (which has a lot of other nice signal processing functions) you can use [scipy.io.wavefile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html#scipy.io.wavfile.read)

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
rate, data_np_ary = scipy.io.wavfile.read('example.wav')
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at SciPy, although I feel like it might be a bit of an overkill for the simple task that I am trying to solve. Nonetheless I am happy to learn about a single function solution to loading a WAVE file into a NumPy array which seems to be the solution for my performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like NumPy really is the way to go. It has managed to load all 12 WAVE files (and do a simple stereo to mono conversion) in just over a second. The code is also more elegant. The only downside of this method is that it only supports 1, 2, 4, and 8-byte integers, but since I am dealing with audio data, this will not be an issue.

The new NumPy solution:

```
data = numpy.frombuffer(raw, numpy.int16)
```